# How can I enforce Oracle to use index and then union instead of full table scan when HQL query is using "OR" condition?

Tags: oracle, performance, hql

Guys:

I have a query written in HQL, which uses 2 OR condition to merge result in the "where" clause part. Hibernate framework gets result very slow because it did a full table scan on table DboX which has huge amount of rows. I want to improve query performance of HQL.

I tested the query in similar sql on Toad, and found it would be much faster if I use union with 3 sub queries instead of "OR" condition.

```
    TypedQuery<DboX> query = this.getTypedQuery(
            "from DboX where ( segId in ( "
                    + "select segId from DboY "
                    + "where fpId.controlNumber = :fpIdControlNumber "
                    + "and fpId.amendmentNumber = :fpIdAmendmentNumber "
                    + " ) or segId in (  "
                    + "select id from DboZ "
                    + "where fpId.controlNumber = :fpIdControlNumber "
                    + "and fpId.amendmentNumber = :fpIdAmendmentNumber "
                    + " ) or mfUuid in (  "
                    + " select uuid from DboU "
                    + "where uSegId in ( "
                    + "select segId from DboY "
                    + "where fpId.controlNumber = :fpIdControlNumber "
                    + "and fpId.amendmentNumber = :fpIdAmendmentNumber "
                    + " ) ) ) and dataSourceName = 'aaaa' and  oId is not null"
                    + " order by oId");


    query.setParameter("fpControlNumber", id.getControlNumber());
    query.setParameter("fpIdAmendmentNumber", id.getAmendmentNumber());

    return super.search(query);
```

However, HQL does not support union, neither I am permitted to update java code to merge result with 3 methods with HQL, as our code is frozen. My manager prefers to get change on back end oracle database instance rather than java code. Does anyone has any suggestion about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all make sure that the Oracle database has updated statistics! If you are lucky the statistics are outdated and the existing query will suddenly pick a better plan when they get updated.

Failing that, if you are allowed to change the code you can use a native query with the SQL you tested in Toad. That is nice as you know that you will get the SQL you have tested and you are not constrained by HQL.

If you are at least allowed to change the HQL (it is also code in my book) you could add hints and instruct Oracle to use the indexes you want. In general I don't like hints, but they have their places. Perhaps this is one of them.

Finally if you really can't touch the application you could try to use a SQL Profile in Oracle to force the plan you want. [Manual creation of a SQL Profile](http://houseofbrick.com/manual-creation-of-a-sql-profile/) explains how to create one manually if Enterprise Manager fails to do what you want. Regardless this is something you need to discuss with your DBA. It requires Enterprise Edition plus "Tuning Pack".

Comment: A word of caution: creating SQL Profiles requires an Enterprise Edition **plus** the "Tuning Pack" (which is charged on top of EE)

Comment: Changed "may require licenses" to EE and tuning pack, thanks for the details.

Comment: Thank you! I got lucky that I found dbms_sqltune package is provided by DBA already under my account.since I am not allowed to change anything on java side, and I tried refresh statistics (it did not work neither), this looks the only way left.